# Wrong font properties from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vba, ms-word

I am reading the properties of a few cells with C# in Excel and writing text with the properties attached to them to Word. Based on their size in Excel, they should be the same size in Word.

However the properties seem 'frozen'. Does anyone have a Clue what might be the issue?

Example;
I have three cells A1, A2 and A3 with font sizes respectively 11, 8, 11.
In Word the three texts get size 11. (For each cell in Excel it gives the size 11 back):

```
docRange.Font.Size = (float)ws.Cells[row, column].Style.Font.Size;
```

This is strange, because you should expect size 11, 8 and 11. However if I try the following in Excel:

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Style.Font.Size
```

It also gives size 11 for every cell. Which should definitely be 11, 8 and 11.

(I already tried calculate automatic and `.calculate();` ).

@Edit 13:13 22-12-2015
If I open a totally new Excel file, put test on A1 and A2, give A1 size 11 and A2 size 8. it gives 11 on `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Style.Font.Size` and also on `MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Range("A2:A2").Style.Font.Size`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel a cell can contain different fonts per character. So you should get the `Font` from the `Characters` object:

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Characters.Font.Size
```

This will only work if all characters in the cell are the same font. If not it will produce an error. To avoid this you could only get the font of the first character for all:

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 4).Characters(1, 1).Font.Size
```

Or you must check every single character.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I noticed that Excel indeed has an 'Cell Style' and an 'Inner-Cell Style'. So instead of using `ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Style.Font.Size`, I should use `ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Font.Size`